# Can Dapper batch a set of stored proc calls?

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

Can [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) batch a set of stored proc calls? I see it supports Multiple Results in the documentation but I'm not sure if you can execute multiple stored proc calls using Dapper.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Dapper supports batching commands for stored procs:

```
connection.Execute("create table #t (i int)");
connection.Execute("create proc #spInsert @i int as insert #t values (@i)");
connection.Execute("#spInsert", new[] { new { i = 1 }, new {i = 2}, new {i = 3} }, 
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

var nums = connection.Query<int>("select * from #t order by i").ToList();

nums[0].IsEqualTo(1);
nums[1].IsEqualTo(2);
nums[2].IsEqualTo(3);
```

The code above reuses the IDbCommand with the text `#spInsert`, 3 times. This makes batching inserts a bit more efficient.

In general if you worry about perf at this level you would wrap the batch call in a transaction.

Additionally Dapper supports whatever batch you decide to send it:

```
connection.Execute(@"
    exec #spInsert @i = @one 
    exec #spInsert @i = @two 
    exec #spInsert @i = @three",
    new { one = 1, two = 2, three = 3 });
```

Which would cause three rows to be inserted.

Further more, if `#spInsert` returned a result set you could use `QueryMultiple` to execute the batch which would give you 3 record sets to iterate through.

Comment: Using a similar approach to send 19 procedure calls as one batch instead of executing them individually I got ~3 fold improvement in performance (141s vs 421s). Used StringBuilder to prepare the query and @param_i names from a list, where i is the index.